# How to read and share and process simultaneously data from parallel processes in Python 2?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Here is my issue.
I am working on a system that acquires data from three different devices (each time, I would like to launch a process that executes a "read_data" loop).

From the three data recorded in realtime, I would like to add a loop on top of that , that would perform an action regarding these data.

Ex (with an obviously really bad semantic, but that's for understanding the idea):

```
Class Sensor1:
read_s1():
 data_s1 = ...
Class Sensor2:
read_s2():
 data_s2 = ...
Class Sensor3:
read_s3():
 data_s3 = ...

main:
read_s1.start()
read_s2.start()
read_s3.start()

while True: #processing and acting regarding realtime data from the three sensors
   if read_s1.data_s1/read_s2.data_s2 + read_s3.data_s3 == 2:
               #do something
```

I tried to use threading and multiprocess, but I could not manage to launch the three threads that read and save in a variable the incoming data, then accessing when I want from an external loop to these data.

Comment: You need to have  synchronization with these threads so that when all are done an iteration, it signals the main thread and the main thread countinues processing the data. You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to be more specific:

I have precisely :

```
thread_1:
   while not e.isSet():
         data1 = read_data1()
thread_2:
   while not e.isSet():
         data2 = read_data2()
thread_3:
   while not e.isSet():
         data3 = read_data3()

if __name__ == 'main':
      thread_1.start()
      thread_2.start()
      thread_3.start()
      while not e.isSet():
            if data1 = 2 and data2 = 3 and data3=4:
                     #do something
```

How am I suppose to use the Lock?
Each thread has a different execution time by iteration as the reading of the data has a different time for each sensor.
Thank you very much!